# how to parse date n java to oracle/sql query?

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jdbc

I have a Query like

```
String query = "Select  * from Orders where ordername = ? and  orderDate > SYSDATE - 2 ";
```

i will pass `**orderName**` and `lastDate` from UI or some constant ("20-9-2016").

orderDate=SYSDATE - 2  --> instead of "2" i will send lastDate.

Is it correct? SYSDATE oracle function and "2" before constant. now "2" can be user input.

How to write a query in java

```
String query = "Select  * from Orders where ordername = ? and  orderDate > SYSDATE - ? ";
```

Is above query correct ? how to write query

```
    public class CheckOrders extends MappingSqlQuery<Object>{
        public PendingOrderExists() {
            super(dataSource, queryConfig
                    .getProperty("query"));
            super.declareParameter(new SqlParameter("ORDERNAME", Types.VARCHAR));
            //orderdate ? how to declare parameter here
            compile();
        }
}
```

Comment: Try this `String query = "Select  * from Orders where ordername = ? and  orderDate= SYSDATE - to_date(?,'dd-m-yyyy')"; `

Comment: Can't you just use orderDate=? and calculate the parameter on java size?

Comment: Sorry my query looks like "String query = "Select  * from Orders where ordername = ? and  orderDate> SYSDATE - ? ";

Comment: the query appears to be correct.

Comment: The query looks correct. Have you tested it and is giving you problems?

Comment: no. in java i will set value like thiss  public class CheckOrders extends MappingSqlQuery<Object>{
  public PendingOrderExists() {
   super(dataSource, queryConfig
     .getProperty("query"));
   super.declareParameter(new SqlParameter("ORDERNAME", Types.VARCHAR));
   //orderdate ? how to declare parameter here
   compile();
  }
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for sysdate-? 
the ? parameter is to be set object of java.sql.Date class instead of java.util.Date class.
java.sql.Date inherits java.util.Date.
java.sql.Date(long time)
here long is number of milliseconds lapsed since jan1,1979.

```
GregorianCalendar gc=new GregorianCalendar(2000, 25, 2);
```

`java.util.Date dt=gc.getTime();`
`long lg=dt.getTime();`
`java.sql.Date sqldt=new java.sql.Date(lg);`
'

pass sqldt object in setDate() method of preparedstatement instance.

hope this works

---

alkaramansari1@gmail.com